# xml with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

list = (glob.glob("/home/anastasiya/PycharmProjects/bachelor/rutexts/*.xhtml"))
for text in list:
print(text)
with open(text, "r", encoding="windows-1251") as file:
    with open("ruscorpus.txt", "a") as file2: 
        for line in file:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(line, "lxml")
            if soup.w is not None:
                        file2.write("{wort}\t{gr}\t{lex}\n".format(
                        lex=soup.w.ana.get('lex'),
                        gr=test(soup.w.ana.get('gr')),
                        wort=soup.w.contents[-1]))
```

I try to get some information from xml. The format is like this.
This program runs, but if we have 2 word in one w tag,  it take the first one as output with whole tags: 
[image]

Comment: why you are reading your `xml` data line wise ?

Answer (score 0):

[Check online demo](http://Check%20online%20demo)

use `soup.find_all('w')` It will give the list of all `w`

soup.w gives only the first occurrence of `w`

Answer (score 0):

1, Your code is trying to read line by line of the file `text`, and then pass it to bs4 to parse. I suggest that you could directly pass the opened file reference to bs4.

2, In bs4, you could find all specific tag like `w` tag content by find_all.

Change your code like this:

```
with open(text, "r", encoding="windows-1251") as file1, open("ruscorpus.txt", "a") as file2: 
    xml_soup = BeautifulSoup(file1,'lxml')
    for w in xml_soup.find_all('w'): # get all w tag and parse them
        file2.write("{wort}\t{gr}\t{lex}\n".format(lex=w.ana.get('lex'),gr=w.ana.get('gr'),wort=w.contents[-1]))
```

Comment: thanks, do you know, how I can get  the punctuation, that is outside of w? <se>
<w>
<ana lex="закрыть" gr="V,pf,tran=sg,act,2p,imper" joined="hyphen"/>
Закр`ой
</w>
-
<w>
<ana lex="закрыть" gr="V,pf,tran=sg,act,2p,imper" joined="hyphen"/>
закр`ой
</w>
.
</se>